# Jellybean Radio Button logic Chip

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, cmos, latch

Below is an LTSpice simulation of a 'radio button' circuilt.
Ignore the bottom button, I am working on a 'reset' mechanism to unlatch any of the other buttons.

The idea is that the button you push, unlatches any other button and latches the button you pushed.

Does anyone know of a jellybean part (some 74 series type chip) that will do this?[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is a jk flipflop. Google will solve the rest for you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller you're a superstar